# Kafka source connector is not pulling the record as expected when records are inserted in source topic from multiple sources

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

In one of my use case i am trying to create a pipeline

whenever i sent the message from custom partition, i sent the timestamp in milliseconds with LONG data type because in the schema, the timestamp column has been defined as long.

Code that i had earlier in custom partition:

```
Date date = new Date();
long timeMilli = date.getTime();
System.out.println("date = " + date.toString() + " , time in millis = " + timeMilli);
```

Display result before i sent the record:

> date = Tue Mar 26 22:02:04 EDT 2019 , time in millis = 1553652124063

value inserted in timestamp column in table2:

> 3/27/2019 2:02:04.063000 AM

Since its taking UK timezone (i believe), i put temporary fix for time being to subtract 4 hours from the current timestamp so that i can match with USA EST timestamp.

```
Date date = new Date();
Date adj_date = DateUtils.addHours(date,-4);
long timeMilli = adj_date.getTime();
System.out.println("date = " + date.toString() + " , time in millis = " + timeMilli);
```

Display result:

> date = Tue Mar 26 22:04:43 EDT 2019 , time in millis = 1553637883826

value inserted in timestamp column in table2:

> 3/26/2019 10:04:43.826000 PM

Please let me know if i am missing anything as i am not sure why this is happening when i sent message from custom partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the hood Jdbc Source Connector use following query:

```sql
SELECT * FROM someTable
WHERE
someTimestampColumn < $endTimetampValue
AND (
    (someTimestampColumn = $beginTimetampValue AND someIncrementalColumn > $lastIncrementedValue)
    OR someTimestampColumn > $beginTimetampValue)
ORDER BY someTimestampColumn, someIncrementalColumn ASC
```

**Summarizing**: The query retrieve rows if their timestamp column's value is *earlier* the current timestamp and is *later* than last checked.

Above parameters are:

1. `beginTimetampValue` - value of timestamp column of last imported record
2. `endTimetampValue` - current timestamp according to the Database
3. `lastIncrementedValue` - value of incremental column of last imported record

I think in your case `Producer` put to the Tables records with *higher timestamp*, than you later insert *manually* (using the query).

When Jdbc Connector checks for new records to import to Kafka it skips them (because they don't fullfil `someTimestampColumn < $endTimetampValue` *timestamp condition*)

You can also change log level to `DEBUG` and see what is going on in logs

Comment: @wardziniak-Thanks much!. yes, you are correct!. connector inserts the UK timestamp(instead of USA EST timezone) if i sent message from custom partition.After fixing(temporary fix) the timestamp issue, source connector2 picks up all the records regardless of source. I do have other issue regarding the timestamp and i have updated the same in original question. Please could you check and let me know your view.. Thanks in advance!.